# Getting Comparison Functions in Scala

Tags: scala

I am playing around with sorting algorithms. I was curious if there were built-in comparison functions for the primitive types. I know it is really easy just to type `(x: Int, y: Int) => x - y`. I just want to know if there is a built in comparison, so I'm not reinventing the wheel. Things obviously get more complicated when it comes to Strings (case-sensitive and culture sensitive). I would be surprised if there wasn't something already built-in.

Comment: `_ - _` is even easier, or, if type inference is not available, `(_: Int) - (_: Int)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a type `A` has an `Ordering` instance, you can get it by writing `Ordering[A]`, and `Ordering` has a `compare` method that you can eta-expand to the function you're looking for:

```
scala> Ordering[Int].compare _
res0: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

As a special case for the primitives (and a few other types), you can refer to the instance directly:

```
scala> Ordering.Int.compare _
res1: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

And more generally, if you've got a type class `F` and `A` has an instance, you can get that instance by writing `implicitly[F[A]]`, so the following also works:

```
scala> implicitly[Ordering[Int]].compare _
res2: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

I'd use the first of these choices, though.